# JQuery - Number items in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dust.js

I would like the number of item's in my list to be numbered from 10 --> 0

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="StoryBoard" id="StoryBoard"> 
{#storylines}
<li>{text|bl|s}</li>    
{/storylines}
</ul>
```

An example of how this would render in the browser would be:

```
<ul class="StoryBoard" id="StoryBoard">
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

However I would like it to render like this:

```
<ul class="StoryBoard" id="StoryBoard">
<li>Test (10)</li>
<li>Test (9)</li>
<li>Test (8)</li>
<li>Test (7)</li>
</ul>
```

There will always be a maximum of 10 items

Comment: I don't have a snippet that does exactly what you ask, but basically you should be able to use .each() to modify each child. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using dustjs, you have access to an `@idx` helper when iterating:

```
{#storylines}
<li>{text|bl|s} ({@idx}{.}{/idx})</li>    
{/storylines}
```

From the dustjs [docs](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/):

> The idx tag passes the numerical index of the current element to the enclosed block.

EDIT: I didn't read your question closely enough - it looks like you're looking for a descending count. the `idx` helper will count up.

EDIT AGAIN: In the comments it was asked if you could just do `{@idx}{10 - .}{/idx}`.

The answer to that is no, because dust doesn't evaluate arbitrary expressions. But if you look at the source of `dust.helpers.idx`, which is where the tag comes from, it's just:

```
function (chunk, context, bodies) { 
  return bodies.block(chunk, context.push(context.stack.index)) 
}
```

It's pushing a new context with the value of the current index of the iteration. It turns out that the `context.stack` object has an attribute `of` that gives you the number of items in the stack, so you can write your own `negidx` helper:

```
dust.helpers.negidx = function(chunk, context, bodies) {
  return bodies.block(chunk, context.push(context.stack.of - context.stack.index));
};
```

At this point, the following will accomplish what the original question asked:

```
{#storylines}
<li>{text|bl|s} ({@negidx}{.}{/negidx})</li>    
{/storylines}
```

[And here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/eg2Mg/)

Comment: Can you not use a sum `10-@idx` (or similar)?

Comment: The short answer is no, but luckily there's a longer answer; I edited my answer to reflect it.

Comment: And +1 for the longer answer. =)

Comment: Thanks just what i'm looking for. I'm new to using helpers with dust how would i go about including them? I've got the dustjs-helpers included in my app.js on node. I can use the normal functions such as idx where would i add the negidx function that you have written?

Comment: anywhere you have access to the `dust` object. The line `dust.helpers.negidx = ...` is where I'm doing it. It's just defining a function on the `dust.helpers` object.

Comment: Ah! i've just added it to my main app.js file and it seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#StoryBoard li').text(function(i,t) { return t + ' (' + (10 -  i )+ ')'});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cEkkt/2/).

The anonymous function in the `text()` method, has two parameters `i` (the index of the current element (as it iterates over *all* the elements matched by the selector)) and `t`, which is the text of the current element.

This, then, returns the current text after appending an opening-bracket, the index and a closing bracket.

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#StoryBoard').find('li').each(function(i){
    $(this).append(' ' + (10 - i ));
});
```

Test? : http://jsbin.com/aduqix/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/GPEth/ - in jQuery
I'm not sure if you want this fix in dust.js or jQuery

```
$(function () {
   var $li   = $('ul#StoryBoard li'),
       count = $li.size();
    $li.each(function (index) {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + (count - index));
    })
});
```